# Puppeteer - Cannot click specific button element on hotel website

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

**Problem**: I am on a hotel website ([Hilton](https://www.hilton.com/en/search/?query=Seattle,%20Washington,%20US&placeId=dx-location::locality::us::wa::seattle&arrivalDate=2023-09-28&departureDate=2023-09-30&flexibleDates=false&numRooms=1&numAdults=1&numChildren=0&room1ChildAges=&room1AdultAges=&specialRateTokens=&sortBy=DISTANCE) and I am trying to click the next page button but I cannot target it.
I am getting `Error: Node is either not clickable or not an HTMLElement` error.

**Please see red arrows drawn on image:**
[image: hotel next page button]

I've tried the following:

```
const nextPageButton = await page.$('#results-pagination .l-display-inline-block .m-pagination-next');

const nextPageButton = await page.$('button[type="button"][class^="btn"] span[class="sr-only"]');

const nextPageButton = await page.$('button[class^="btn"] svg[role="img"] path[class="stroke-text"]');

const nextPageButton = await page.$('button[type="button"]:not([disabled]) path.stroke-text');

const nextPageButton = await page.$('button[class^="btn"]:not([disabled]) span[class="sr-only"]');

const nextPageButton = await page.$('[class^="pointer-events-auto"] button[class^="btn"]:not([disabled]) .sr-only');
```

code:

```
// TODO: Implement logic to scroll to the bottom of the page, and scrape 
  // After grabbing page 1 hotels, scroll to bottom of the page (still at page 1)
  await scroll_to_bottom_of_page(page);

  // Check if there is a next page navigator at bottom of page 1
  // !NOT WORKING
  // const nextPageButton = await page.$('#results-pagination .l-display-inline-block .m-pagination-next');
  // const nextPageButton = await page.$('button[type="button"][class^="btn"] span[class="sr-only"]');
  // const nextPageButton = await page.$('button[class^="btn"] svg[role="img"] path[class="stroke-text"]');
  // const nextPageButton = await page.$('button[type="button"]:not([disabled]) path.stroke-text');
  // const nextPageButton = await page.$('button[class^="btn"]:not([disabled]) span[class="sr-only"]');
  // const nextPageButton = await page.$('[class^="pointer-events-auto"] button[class^="btn"]:not([disabled]) .sr-only');

  // If nextPageButton exists (we are still at bottom of page 1)
  if (nextPageButton) {
    // test print
    console.log("next page button exists")
    // Click the nextPageButton, because we already have page 1 information in our array
    await nextPageButton.click()
    // Wait for the navigation to complete before continuing with next actions 
    await page.waitForNavigation();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to scroll down, then use this XPath:

```
const nextPageButton = await page.$x('//button[@type="button" and starts-with(./span/text(), "Next Page")]');
await nextPageButton[0].click()
```

Tested in firefox or chrome with

```
$x('//button[@type="button" and starts-with(./span/text(), "Next Page")]')[0].click()
```